# DirectX 11 Blending

Tags: directx, directx-11, directx-12

How can i access pixel colors of destination pixel in pixel shader, in order to use my specific blending equation, when control goes to pixel shader i only have the source pixel position and color, i want to know what is the color of destination pixel at that time..?

One approach i have heard is by using textures, but i am not able to find the way through textures.

Programmable blending is not allowed in directX 11, but with some hacks it is possible.

```
void D3D12HelloTriangle::LoadPipeline()
{
    UINT dxgiFactoryFlags = 0;

    ComPtr<IDXGIFactory4> factory;
    ThrowIfFailed(CreateDXGIFactory2(dxgiFactoryFlags, IID_PPV_ARGS(&factory)));

    //Device Creation
    {
        ComPtr<IDXGIAdapter1> hardwareAdapter;
        GetHardwareAdapter(factory.Get(), &hardwareAdapter);

        ThrowIfFailed(D3D12CreateDevice(
            hardwareAdapter.Get(),
            D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_device)
            ));
    }


    // Describe and create the command queue.
    D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_DESC queueDesc = {};
    queueDesc.Flags = D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_FLAG_NONE;
    queueDesc.Type = D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT;

    ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommandQueue(&queueDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_commandQueue)));

    // Describe and create the swap chain.
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = {};
    swapChainDesc.BufferCount = FrameCount;
    swapChainDesc.Width = m_width;
    swapChainDesc.Height = m_height;
    swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_DISCARD;
    swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;

    ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain1> swapChain;
    ThrowIfFailed(factory->CreateSwapChainForCoreWindow(
        m_commandQueue.Get(),       // Swap chain needs the queue so that it can force a flush on it.
        reinterpret_cast<IUnknown*>(Windows::UI::Core::CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread()),
        &swapChainDesc,
        nullptr,
        &swapChain
        ));

    ThrowIfFailed(swapChain.As(&m_swapChain));
    m_frameIndex = m_swapChain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex();





    // Create descriptor heaps.
    {
        // Describe and create a render target view (RTV) descriptor heap.
        D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC rtvHeapDesc = {};
        rtvHeapDesc.NumDescriptors = FrameCount;
        rtvHeapDesc.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV;
        rtvHeapDesc.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE;
        ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateDescriptorHeap(&rtvHeapDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_rtvHeap)));

        m_rtvDescriptorSize = m_device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV);
    }

    // Create frame resources.
    {
        CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHandle(m_rtvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());

        // Create a RTV for each frame.
        for (UINT n = 0; n < FrameCount; n++)
        {
            ThrowIfFailed(m_swapChain->GetBuffer(n, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_renderTargets[n])));
            m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(m_renderTargets[n].Get(), nullptr, rtvHandle);

            rtvHandle.Offset(1, m_rtvDescriptorSize);
        }
    }

    ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommandAllocator(D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_commandAllocator)));
}

// Load the sample assets.
void D3D12HelloTriangle::LoadAssets()
{
    // Create an empty root signature.
    {
        CD3DX12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rootSignatureDesc;
        rootSignatureDesc.Init(0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT);

        ComPtr<ID3DBlob> signature;
        ComPtr<ID3DBlob> error;
        ThrowIfFailed(D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&rootSignatureDesc, D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1, &signature, &error));
        ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateRootSignature(0, signature->GetBufferPointer(), signature->GetBufferSize(), IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_rootSignature)));
    }

    // Create the pipeline state, which includes compiling and loading shaders.
    {
        ComPtr<ID3DBlob> vertexShader;
        ComPtr<ID3DBlob> pixelShader;

#if defined(_DEBUG)
        // Enable better shader debugging with the graphics debugging tools.
        UINT compileFlags = D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG | D3DCOMPILE_SKIP_OPTIMIZATION;
#else
        UINT compileFlags = 0;
#endif


        ThrowIfFailed(D3DCompileFromFile(GetAssetFullPath(L"VertexShader.hlsl").c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, "VSMain", "vs_5_0", compileFlags, 0, &vertexShader, nullptr));
        ThrowIfFailed(D3DCompileFromFile(GetAssetFullPath(L"PixelShader.hlsl").c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, "PSMain", "ps_5_0", compileFlags, 0, &pixelShader, nullptr));


        // Define the vertex input layout.
        D3D12_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputElementDescs[] =
        {
            { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
            { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, D3D12_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
            { "DELAY", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT, 0, D3D12_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D12_INPUT_CLASSIFICATION_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },

        };






        // Describe and create the graphics pipeline state object (PSO).
        D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC psoDesc = {};
        psoDesc.InputLayout = { inputElementDescs, _countof(inputElementDescs) };
        psoDesc.pRootSignature = m_rootSignature.Get();
        psoDesc.VS = CD3DX12_SHADER_BYTECODE(vertexShader.Get());
        psoDesc.PS = CD3DX12_SHADER_BYTECODE(pixelShader.Get());
        psoDesc.RasterizerState = CD3DX12_RASTERIZER_DESC(D3D12_DEFAULT);
        psoDesc.BlendState = CD3DX12_BLEND_DESC(D3D12_DEFAULT);
        psoDesc.DepthStencilState.DepthEnable = FALSE;
        psoDesc.DepthStencilState.StencilEnable = FALSE;
        psoDesc.SampleMask = 1;
        psoDesc.PrimitiveTopologyType = D3D12_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TYPE_TRIANGLE;
        psoDesc.NumRenderTargets = 2;
        psoDesc.RTVFormats[0] = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        psoDesc.RTVFormats[1] = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
        //psoDesc.RTVFormats[2] = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;

        psoDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        psoDesc.RasterizerState.CullMode = D3D12_CULL_MODE_NONE;
        //ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateGraphicsPipelineState(&psoDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pipelineState)));

        D3D12_GRAPHICS_PIPELINE_STATE_DESC transparentPsoDesc = psoDesc;

        D3D12_RENDER_TARGET_BLEND_DESC transparencyBlendDesc;

        transparencyBlendDesc.BlendEnable = true;

        transparencyBlendDesc.LogicOpEnable = false;

        transparencyBlendDesc.SrcBlend = D3D12_BLEND_ONE;

        transparencyBlendDesc.DestBlend = D3D12_BLEND_ONE;

        transparencyBlendDesc.BlendOp = D3D12_BLEND_OP_MAX;

        transparencyBlendDesc.SrcBlendAlpha = D3D12_BLEND_ONE;

        transparencyBlendDesc.DestBlendAlpha = D3D12_BLEND_ONE;

        transparencyBlendDesc.BlendOpAlpha = D3D12_BLEND_OP_MAX;

        transparencyBlendDesc.LogicOp = D3D12_LOGIC_OP_NOOP;

        transparencyBlendDesc.RenderTargetWriteMask = D3D12_COLOR_WRITE_ENABLE_ALL;

        transparentPsoDesc.BlendState.RenderTarget[0] =
            transparencyBlendDesc;

        ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateGraphicsPipelineState(&transparentPsoDesc,IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_pipelineState)));
        ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommandList(0, D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT, m_commandAllocator.Get(), m_pipelineState.Get(), IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_commandList)));


    }


    // Command lists are created in the recording state, but there is nothing
    // to record yet. The main loop expects it to be closed, so close it now.
    ThrowIfFailed(m_commandList->Close());

    // Create the vertex buffer.
    {
        // Define the geometry for a triangle.
        Vertex triangleVertices[] =
        {
            { { 0.0f, 0.0f * m_aspectRatio, 0.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,1.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f } },
            { { 0.25f, 0.0f * m_aspectRatio, 0.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f } },
            { { 0.0f, 0.25f * m_aspectRatio, 0.0f },{ 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f } },
            { { 0.25f, 0.25f * m_aspectRatio, 0.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f,1.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f } },
        };




        // Cube vertices. Each vertex has a position and a color.
        Vertex triangleVertices2[] =
        {
            { { 0.0f, 0.0f * m_aspectRatio, 0.0f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f } },
            { { 0.5f, 0.0f * m_aspectRatio, 0.0f },{ 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f } },
            { { 0.0f, 0.5f * m_aspectRatio, 0.0f },{0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f } },
            { { 0.5f, 0.5f * m_aspectRatio, 0.0f },{ 0.0f,1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f },{ 0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,1.0f } },
        };

        const UINT vertexBufferSize = sizeof(triangleVertices);

        const UINT my_vertexBufferSize  = sizeof(triangleVertices2);





        // Note: using upload heaps to transfer static data like vert buffers is not 
        // recommended. Every time the GPU needs it, the upload heap will be marshalled 
        // over. Please read up on Default Heap usage. An upload heap is used here for 
        // code simplicity and because there are very few verts to actually transfer.


        ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommittedResource(
            &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD),
            D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
            &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(vertexBufferSize),
            D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
            nullptr,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_vertexBuffer)));


        ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommittedResource(
            &CD3DX12_HEAP_PROPERTIES(D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_UPLOAD),
            D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE,
            &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_DESC::Buffer(my_vertexBufferSize),
            D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ,
            nullptr,
            IID_PPV_ARGS(&my_vertexBuffer)));




        // Copy the triangle data to the vertex buffer.
        UINT8* pVertexDataBegin;
        CD3DX12_RANGE readRange(0, 0);      // We do not intend to read from this resource on the CPU.
        ThrowIfFailed(m_vertexBuffer->Map(0, &readRange, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pVertexDataBegin)));

        UINT8* my_pVertexDataBegin;
        CD3DX12_RANGE my_readRange(0, 0);       // We do not intend to read from this resource on the CPU.
        ThrowIfFailed(my_vertexBuffer->Map(0, &my_readRange, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&my_pVertexDataBegin)));


        memcpy(pVertexDataBegin, triangleVertices, sizeof(triangleVertices));

        m_vertexBuffer->Unmap(0, nullptr);
        memcpy(my_pVertexDataBegin, triangleVertices2, sizeof(triangleVertices2));

        my_vertexBuffer->Unmap(0, nullptr);




        // Initialize the vertex buffer view.
        m_vertexBufferView[0].BufferLocation = m_vertexBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
        m_vertexBufferView[0].StrideInBytes = sizeof(Vertex);
        m_vertexBufferView[0].SizeInBytes = vertexBufferSize;


        m_vertexBufferView[1].BufferLocation = my_vertexBuffer->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
        m_vertexBufferView[1].StrideInBytes = sizeof(Vertex);
        m_vertexBufferView[1].SizeInBytes = vertexBufferSize;


    }

    // Create synchronization objects and wait until assets have been uploaded to the GPU.
    {
        ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateFence(0, D3D12_FENCE_FLAG_NONE, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_fence)));
        m_fenceValue = 1;

    }

}

// Update frame-based values.
void D3D12HelloTriangle::OnUpdate()
{
}

// Render the scene.
void D3D12HelloTriangle::OnRender()
{
    // Record all the commands we need to render the scene into the command list.
    PopulateCommandList();

    // Execute the command list.
    ID3D12CommandList* ppCommandLists[] = { m_commandList.Get() };
    m_commandQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(_countof(ppCommandLists), ppCommandLists);

    // Present the frame.
    ThrowIfFailed(m_swapChain->Present(1, 0));

    WaitForPreviousFrame();
}

void D3D12HelloTriangle::OnDestroy()
{
    // Ensure that the GPU is no longer referencing resources that are about to be
    // cleaned up by the destructor.
    WaitForPreviousFrame();

}

void D3D12HelloTriangle::PopulateCommandList()
{
    // Command list allocators can only be reset when the associated 
    // command lists have finished execution on the GPU; apps should use 
    // fences to determine GPU execution progress.
    ThrowIfFailed(m_commandAllocator->Reset());

    // However, when ExecuteCommandList() is called on a particular command 
    // list, that command list can then be reset at any time and must be before 
    // re-recording.
    ThrowIfFailed(m_commandList->Reset(m_commandAllocator.Get(), m_pipelineState.Get()));

    // Set necessary state.
    m_commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(m_rootSignature.Get());
    m_commandList->RSSetViewports(1, &m_viewport);

    m_commandList->RSSetScissorRects(1, &m_scissorRect);

    // Indicate that the back buffer will be used as a render target.

    //m_commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(m_renderTargets[m_frameIndex].Get(), D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET));

    CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHandle(m_rtvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(), m_frameIndex, m_rtvDescriptorSize);
    m_commandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &rtvHandle, FALSE, nullptr);

    // Record commands.

    const float clearColor[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

    m_commandList->ClearRenderTargetView(rtvHandle, clearColor, 0, nullptr);
    m_commandList->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLESTRIP);

    m_commandList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_vertexBufferView[1]);
    m_commandList->DrawInstanced(4, 1, 0, 0);

    m_commandList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, m_vertexBufferView);
    m_commandList->DrawInstanced(4, 1, 0, 0);



    // Indicate that the back buffer will now be used to present.
    m_commandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &CD3DX12_RESOURCE_BARRIER::Transition(m_renderTargets[m_frameIndex].Get(), D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT));

    ThrowIfFailed(m_commandList->Close());
}

void D3D12HelloTriangle::WaitForPreviousFrame()
{
    // WAITING FOR THE FRAME TO COMPLETE BEFORE CONTINUING IS NOT BEST PRACTICE.
    // This is code implemented as such for simplicity. The D3D12HelloFrameBuffering
    // sample illustrates how to use fences for efficient resource usage and to
    // maximize GPU utilization.

    // Signal and increment the fence value.
    const UINT64 fence = m_fenceValue;
    ThrowIfFailed(m_commandQueue->Signal(m_fence.Get(), fence));
    m_fenceValue++;


    m_frameIndex = m_swapChain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex();
}
```

Comment: You just plugin your values in this blending equation: src pixel * src blend factor + dest pixel * dest bland factor.

Comment: What is this code? Please reduce it to the minimum that is essential for the question. If your custom blending function cannot be modeled with the available framework, you need to pass the background image as a shader resource to the pixel shader and sample it at your current pixel position. However, you cannot have the same texture bound as both render target and shader resource, obviously.